# How to Rotate objects with multiple pivot points

Tags: animation

How do i create an animation for the shape shown

Rotate circle but at the same time swing the feet outwards.

This is the first time I have done animation so please treat me as a beginner.
The rotation of all 3 items is easy but i get stuck trying make the two feet rotate outwards at the same time, how do i do this as when I change the pivot point it breaks the grouped rotation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, you either have to make those three parts individual objects that are rotated separately, but the "feet" parented to the circle. Or if you want/need everything in a single object, you will need an armature to move the parts with bones. Shape keys would not work because they cannot rotate the mesh. By the way, why is the object's origin point changing from screenshot to screenshot? Is this intentionally?

Comment: If these are 4 separate objects you can parent them: parent the legs to the plane, parent the plane to the circle. You can also use an armatureand parent each object to a bone. If these are 4 meshes within one unique object, use an armature and parent each part to a bone.

Answer (score 3):

If these are 4 separate objects you first need to make sure that their origin is where the center of rotation is supposed to be (when you'll animate it's the object origin that will be taken into account, not the 3D cursor). Then parent them this way: parent the legs to the plane (select the child, shift select the parent, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Set Parent to Object*), parent the plane to the circle.

You could also use an armature and parent each object to a bone but you need to learn a bit about armatures.

Comment: They are 4 seperate objects yes, This is a simplified version of my real drawing, these objects have many other objects.
How do I add a parent?
Or am I better to learn how to add bones?

Comment: To parent, select the child, shift select the parent and Ctrl P > Set Parent to Object. Bones work as well, but you need to learn armatures.

Comment: And these are non-deforming, so no need for armatures? ( I've always wondered why folks use bones for mechanics... is that just for export?)

Comment: For mechanics like robots you can for example use IK constraint if you use armature